# Sourcing a script from another script fails

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script in a file - install.sh - with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/master/kvminstall.sh
sh kvminstall.sh
source ~/.kre/kvm/kvm.sh
```

Everything works except for the last line which gives the error:

```
**install.sh: 4: install.sh: source: not found**
```

I then replaced `source`with `.` but then get the error:

```
**install.sh: 363: /home/vagrant/.kre/kvm/kvm.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ";;")**
```

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this error message:

```
install.sh: 4: install.sh: source: not found
```

That means that the script is *not* being executed by `bash`.  This error likely comes from `dash` which is the default shell under Ubuntu.

Try running your script as:

```
bash /path/to/install.sh
```

#### More

Observe the line:

```
sh kvminstall.sh
```

This starts `kvminstall.sh` using the default shell (`dash`).  However, `kvminstall.sh` is a `bash` script.  (you can tell this by looking at its first line.)  Thus, use instead:

```
bash kvminstall.sh
```

Comment: This makes the error message disappear but the sourcing doesn't seem to have had any effect because kvm isn't installed and the last printed line now says **Type 'source /home/vagrant/.kre/kvm/kvm.sh' to start using kvm**

Comment: @Christian That message does not indicate a problem.  It is the normal message that that kvminstall.sh prints when it is finished.  See also my updated answer for a solution to another potential issue that you may be experiencing.

Comment: You're right. However, the sourcing doesn't seem to have any effect since when I enter `kvm` in my terminal it isn't found (had it  been properly installed it would have printed out the manual for kvm).

Comment: _"when I enter kvm in my terminal it isn't found"_  That means that it is not on your PATH.

Comment: Ah but of course. Running **source install.sh** instead of **bash install.sh** will make kvm to be added to the PATH. Thanks!